# Trying to understand Prolog error: existence_error

Tags: prolog, logic

I am trying to understand what is going on with a couple Prolog queries. I have the following rules:

```
 similar(a,aa).   
 similar(aa,aaa).
 similar(X,X).
 similar(X,Y) :- similar(Y,X).
 similar(X,Y) :- similar(X,Z), similar(Z,Y).
```

I will then try to do a basic query:

```
 ?- similar(a,aaa).
```

Which results in the following error:

```
 uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,similar/0),similar/0)
```

It would seem to me that it would return `True` because it would look to see that `similar(a,aa)` and `similar(aa,aaa)`, thus satisfying the second horn clause.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your query never ends... When you do `similar(X,Y) :- similar(Y,X).` you create a loop

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the inf recursion?

Comment: You need to save in a list the element you analyze in each iteration and then, for each iteration, check if the element you consider in the current iteration is in this list or not.